# Should Rest services have a viewmodel?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I have an angular client and a Rest service which has a rich domain object. When calling the rest POST endpoint from angular should the client map its view to an object that is the json version ( which becomes the spring requestbody) of the services domain?

Or should the client map to a simple domain and the service maps the simple request object to its rich domain object and then performs actions I the domain object?

What is best practice when mapping back and forth between view model on client and rich domain object on service?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends.

If it is truly a RESTful service, a "viewmodel" makes no sense, as this should basically be the "resource" in the service.
Usually you would use [ng-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for RESTful services which will do the one-to-one mapping for you.

On the otherhand if it is some wannabe RESTful service where it is not really resource oriented (basically just a JSON service), it might make sense, ... but most likely not.

Comment: i am using ng-resource to talk to my Restful service, which returns back a rich object, which has objects nested. This in turn makes the json object that the resource is copying to be a complicated one. For simplicity i am binding my view to a more simpler model with ng-model. I am mapping the resource object (js object) to the viewmodel at my client. What this means is i have extensive mapper functions at my client side. Is this a wrong implementation? am i understanding things incorrectly?

Comment: In that case you are properly doing the right thing. This real problem is that the server shouldn't return something that is that complicated